# w3c document.forms[0].fieldname equivalent

Tags: javascript, forms, w3c

I've been using

```
document.forms[0].fieldname.value
```

to get values in javascript from a form, but I'd like to use a name to reference the field and not a 0, what would be the equivalent these days since `<form name="formname">` isn't compliant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to add an id to the input: `<input id="fieldname" />` and reference the value from JavaScript like so:

```
document.getElementById('fieldname').value
```

or, if you're using jQuery

```
$('#fieldname').val();
```

Answer (score 6):

The [forms collection](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-html.html#attribute-forms) is standard DOM 1, there is nothing wrong with using it.

```
document.forms.formId.elements.field
```

Answer (score 2):

Would giving the form a name= value and referring to it in the document.forms 'array' by name work?

i.e.: (much abbreviated)

```
<form name="form1">.insert.your.elements.here.with.name.attribute.set.</form>
```

and in JS:

```
document.forms["form1"]["form_item_name"].value;
```

I'm a rank amateur so if this is wrong, pls leave me a constructive criticism... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Giving each element an unique id and using this id with the [getElementById](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-getelementbyid.php) function is recommended:

```
var value = document.getElementById('idofelement').value;
```

Answer (score 1):

(`document.forms` is still supported. You can keep it.)

The best way to to give the field an `id` and use `document.getElementById`.

```
<input type="text" name="fooName" id="fooId" />
...
document.getElementById("fooId").value;
```

If you can't add an `id`, you can still use `document.getElementsByName`, but it will return an array instead of a single element because many may share the same name.

```
document.getElementsByName("fooName")[0].value;
```