# back button not working in internet explorer, working good in mozilla firefox and google chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jsp, struts

I have a form page where I have a back button and a print button both on the top and bottom of the page(coded in javascript). The back button at the bottom of the page is not working in the Internet Explorer whereas the top one and both the print buttons works good. The code chunk is same for both of back button. In addition all the buttons are are working well in Mozilla Firefox and Google chrome. For reference the codes for the back button go like this

```
<html:submit onclick="javascript:document.forms[0].action.value='back';" >
<fmt:message key="form.button.back"/>
</html:submit>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is that? That doesn't look like HTML? Is this some kind of transformation language? What are you using to construct this code?

Comment: its a JSP page in the Struts framework. form.button.back is defined in the properties file, so it works good.

Comment: Are they both inside the same form element (the first one in the page)? The form needs to be submitted before it will have any effect, so a click on such a button outside the first form won't have any effect. Note also you should not use the meaningless `javascript:` label, and if you have to call the field `action` you are best off accessing it as `someform.elements.action` (or by `getElementById`) to avoid confusion with the `form.action` property.

Comment: ya both of the back buttons are inside the same form element

Comment: Please cut down the JSP to smallest possible amount of code which still reproduces the problem (so: remove all unnecessary tags, markup, css, JS, etc), then rightclick page in browser, choose *View Source* and copypaste that into your question (with code formatting). Post the original JSP source code along it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Document.forms is not W3C standard anymore.

See [w3c document.forms[0].fieldname equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810573/w3c-document-forms0-fieldname-equivalent)

Also make sure your input field got a proper type and name field with proper values.

> "In other words, there is no such property as document.forms[0].action.value unless you have an element with an ID of "action" on your page, and as Eric posted, that is not a very good idea."

See http://forums.asp.net/p/1354778/2775719.aspx

Anyway, I don't think that is the issue here. If I try to reproduce the scenario, I also get no back action in my browser. That is because if you change the value of an input form it will just change the text that the button is actually displaying in the browser to the String 'back'.

If you really want the browser to surf back in browsing history you have to code it like this:

```
document.forms[0].myID.onclick = history.back();
```

In the 'action' property of a submit-type input form you usually define a server side script that will receive the values of the textfields of the form that the user did fill out.

```
<form>
    <input id="myID" name="myNam" action="serve.php" value="myVal" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: It's however still supported by practically all browsers.