# Remove added element from form doesn't work

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to remove an element (that I added dynamically) from the page completely, but it seems to not quite be working right. The problem is that after I remove an element from the page, it still appears in `document.forms` - which is causing me an issue since the page automatically grabs it later when processing some other data.  I cannot change the downstream actions, but I'm wondering if  there is a better way to delete the input. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wTNFq/4/) for an example.

Chrome 18 and FF 13 both work the same (broken) while IE 9 works correctly, but I need it to work in all browsers - in quirks mode.

Comment: Consider using jQuery instead of Prototype.js. The lastest release of Prototype is already 2 years out of date.

Comment: @Diodeus: I would LOVE to, but unfortunately this is a corporate product and with the changes we made to the Prototype library upper level folks are VERY resistant to changing. Personally I would switch to jQuery if I had my way...

Comment: That sucks. Knowing jQuery can get you a job, Prototype will not. I made the switch three years ago because of that fact.

Comment: @Diodeus: Oh I know, but the rest of this job FAR outweighs the downside of using Prototype :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `document.getElementById` instead of `document.forms`:

http://jsfiddle.net/wTNFq/6/

```
var testfield = document.getElementById('testfield');

console.log('VALUE before: ' + testfield .value);

document.getElementById('wrapper').removeChild(testfield);

console.log('VALUE after: ' + document.getElementById('testfield').value);
```

​EDIT: according to the accepted answer for [w3c document.forms[0].fieldname equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810573/w3c-document-forms0-fieldname-equivalent), your problem may be related to using the `name` attribute on an `input` element.

Comment: While this makes sense, it unfortunately doesn't solve my issue since I can't change the downstream code (and it gets its information from `document.forms`). However, unless someone can get a better solution in the next day or so I'll accept this and hack in some workaround.

Comment: I must be reading a different doc than that person posted - I read it as saying that we REQUIRE a `name` attribute on an input to be included in a form submit - I believe the idea is that we shouldn't access normal, non-input page items (divs, spans, etc) by name

Answer (score 0):

In your example you were missing all of the `#` tags from your jQuery selectors. When you are selecting an element by it's id you must always include a `#` before the name and for classes include the `.` like this - `$('#wrapper')`.

I fixed your example here --> [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wTNFq/5/) by doing the following

`$('#wrapper #testField').remove();`

Hope this helps

Comment: he is using prototype, not jquery.

Comment: @josh.trow Despite being horribly wrong, I will leave my answer here for now as If you did consider using jQuery then this example would work for you.